# Not to remove object without confirmation

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django

I try to remove elements from my table in my django project, but I would like to have such a removal to be confirmed. Using this article 
http://www.developmentwall.com/delete-row-from-html-table-jquery/ 
I wrote such function:

```
<script>
function deleteAjax(row_id){
    $.ajax({
        url: "delete_item/"+ row_id +"/",
        type: "POST",
        data: {'id':row_id},
        success: function (){
            if(!confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')){
                ev.preventDefault();
                return false;
            }else{
                $('#my_row_'+row_id).remove();
            }
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

Unfortunately, despite of the fact that I click that I won't to delete object, the object is removed.

Have you any hints? I suppose that it can be something wrong with `ev`, but I am fairly new to javascript and ajax and I do not know how to cope with this.

Comment: Where is the "ev" object coming from?  I don't see a click function passing it in?

Comment: I tried to use example like in link in the question and there object "ev" is not passed? But, indeed, it should be passed somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
<script>
function deleteAjax(row_id){
    if (!confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')) { return; }
    $.ajax({
        url: "delete_item/"+ row_id +"/",
        type: "POST",
        data: {'id':row_id},
        success: function (){
            $('#my_row_'+row_id).remove();
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

Comment: +1 It works! Thank you so much! I will accept it within few minutes :)